# Jquery Datepicker appering twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Right this has been painful, i've spent 6 hours debugging code(yes its been such a wasteful day) to find out why the same month appears twice,

[image]

So I've narrowed it down to this section of code

```
$("#opener").click(function () {
    $("#Mydialog").dialog("open");
});
$(function () {
    $("#Mydialog").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true });
});

$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Any ideas of why this would cause it to display the same month twice? (help me put me out of my misery)?

Comment: Can you post your HTML? And a jsFiddle would help.

Answer (score 0):

Not a true answer, but what happens if you try this?

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    $("#opener").click(function () {
        $("#Mydialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```